# Generate XML path format from SQL table

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml

I was trying to get an XML from a SQL table:

My Table

```
------------
-- Table1 --
------------

ID    Flight1    Flight2
--------------------------
1     F0123      F0789
2     F0345      F0678

Query:

Select
    A.[ID],
    A.[Flight1] as "FlightDescription/Number",
    A.[Flight2] as "FlightDescription/Number"
from
    [Table1] A
for xml path('Flight'), root('Flights')
```

My expected result is:

```
 <Flights>
  <Flight>
    <ID>1</ID>
    <FlightDescription>
        <Number>F0123</Number>
    </FlightDescription>
    <FlightDescription>
        <Number>F0789</Number>
    </FlightDescription>
  </Flight>
  <Flight>
    <ID>2</ID>
    <FlightDescription>
        <Number>F0345</Number>
    </FlightDescription>
    <FlightDescription>
        <Number>F0678</Number>
    </FlightDescription>
  </Flight>
</Flights>
```

But instead of that I'm getting this:

```
<Flights>
  <Flight>
    <ID>1</ID>
    <FlightDescription>
        <Number>F0123F0789</Number>
    </FlightDescription>
  </Flight>
  <Flight>
    <ID>2</ID>
    <FlightDescription>
        <Number>F0345F0678</Number>
    </FlightDescription>
  </Flight>
</Flights>
```

I can figure it out... In my table i have more than 4 flight numbers for each ID so i would like to know if there is a way to have all of them in the way i need.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you really specify the same column alias twice?

Comment: If i specify the alias different i will get under FlightDescription <Number>F0123</Number><Number2>F0789</Number2> and i dont want that, each number should be a different flight description.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is another slightly more elaborate way. *XQuery* and its *FLWOR* expression. This way you shape your XML explicitly. It is easy to create, understand, make any modifications, and maintain down the road.

> SQL

```
-- DDL and sample data population, start
DECLARE @tbl TABLE (ID INT PRIMARY KEY, Flight1 VARCHAR(20), Flight2 VARCHAR(20));

INSERT INTO @tbl (ID, Flight1, Flight2) VALUES
(1, 'F0123', 'F0789'),
(2, 'F0345', 'F0678');
-- DDL and sample data population, end

SELECT (
SELECT * 
FROM @tbl
FOR XML PATH('r'), TYPE, ROOT('root')).query('<Flights>
{
    for $x in /root/r
    return <Flight>
        {$x/ID}
        <FlightDescription>
            <number>{data($x/Flight1)}</number>
            <number>{data($x/Flight2)}</number>
        </FlightDescription>
    </Flight>
}
</Flights>'
);
```

> Output

```
<Flights>
  <Flight>
    <ID>1</ID>
    <FlightDescription>
      <number>F0123</number>
      <number>F0789</number>
    </FlightDescription>
  </Flight>
  <Flight>
    <ID>2</ID>
    <FlightDescription>
      <number>F0345</number>
      <number>F0678</number>
    </FlightDescription>
  </Flight>
</Flights>
```

Comment: check the execution plan and the excessive memory grant...why create an xml from data and xquery on it and not simply create the xml directly from the data?

Comment: I completely understand what you are saying. We are on the same page. However, slight modification, and the OP is complete lost. It is not always just about performance.

Comment: lptr, please connect with me on the LinkedIn

Answer (score 2):

Create an empty node between the two FlightDescription/Number elements/nodes.

```
declare @f table
(
Id int,
Flight1 varchar(20),
Flight2 varchar(20)
);

insert into @f(Id, Flight1, Flight2)
values
(1, 'F0123', 'F0789'),
(2, 'F0345', 'F0678');

Select
    A.[ID],
    A.[Flight1] as 'FlightDescription/Number',
    '',
    A.[Flight2] as 'FlightDescription/Number'
from
    @f A
for xml path('Flight'), root('Flights');
```

Comment: Hi man, what if i want to merge the <FlightDescription> with inside the 2 flight numbers? i would like to have:
<FlightDescription>
        <Number>F0123</Number>
        <Number>F0789</Number>
    </FlightDescription>

Comment: then you create the empty node at the FlightDescription level :    `'' AS 'FlightDescription',`